# Xcode error "not found for architecture". trying basic C++ w/o libraries

Tags: c++, xcode, macos

I am getting this "not found for architecture" error that I'm seeing a lot of posts about, but I haven't figured out a solution from reading some other posts...  (Seems to me most of them focus on libraries linking, but I don't think I'm using any libraries...)

I am trying to do very basic C++ stuff, basically just pass around an object to another function in another class.  I'm a beginner in C++ coming mostly from Java, so I'm not even totally sure if I'm writing wrong code or if it's an IDE problem...

My code:`

```
class One{
public:
    One();
    int value;
};

One::One(){
    value = 5;
}


class Two{
public:
    Two();
    One one;
    int doSomething(One* oneArgument);
    int somethingThatCallsDoSomething();
};

int Two::doSomething(One *oneArgument){
    return oneArgument->value;
}

int Two::somethingThatCallsDoSomething(){
    doSomething(&one);
    return 0;
}



int main(){
    Two two;
    return two.somethingThatCallsDoSomething();
}
```

`

My errors is that I get a 'Build Failed' with two errors:

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Two::Two()", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

This is the additional text above (I have on idea what it's about..):

Ld /Users/Nafty/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/attempt_for_even_simpler_version_of_issue-gjurwihlodxqbjgukkxvnrjxcmti/Build/Products/Debug/attempt\ for\ even\ simpler\ version\ of\ issue.app/Contents/MacOS/attempt\ for\ even\ simpler\ version\ of\ issue normal x86_64
    cd "/Users/Nafty/Documents/Philosophy/experiment 1 with Xcode/SDL2.0 w/attempt for even simpler version of issue"
    export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.9
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk -L/Users/Nafty/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/attempt_for_even_simpler_version_of_issue-gjurwihlodxqbjgukkxvnrjxcmti/Build/Products/Debug -L/opt/local/lib -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/lib -F/Users/Nafty/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/attempt_for_even_simpler_version_of_issue-gjurwihlodxqbjgukkxvnrjxcmti/Build/Products/Debug -F/Library/Frameworks -filelist /Users/Nafty/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/attempt_for_even_simpler_version_of_issue-gjurwihlodxqbjgukkxvnrjxcmti/Build/Intermediates/attempt\ for\ even\ simpler\ version\ of\ issue.build/Debug/attempt\ for\ even\ simpler\ version\ of\ issue.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/attempt\ for\ even\ simpler\ version\ of\ issue.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -framework cocoa -framework SDL2 -stdlib=libc++ -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/Nafty/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/attempt_for_even_simpler_version_of_issue-gjurwihlodxqbjgukkxvnrjxcmti/Build/Intermediates/attempt\ for\ even\ simpler\ version\ of\ issue.build/Debug/attempt\ for\ even\ simpler\ version\ of\ issue.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/attempt\ for\ even\ simpler\ version\ of\ issue_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/Nafty/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/attempt_for_even_simpler_version_of_issue-gjurwihlodxqbjgukkxvnrjxcmti/Build/Products/Debug/attempt\ for\ even\ simpler\ version\ of\ issue.app/Contents/MacOS/attempt\ for\ even\ simpler\ version\ of\ issue

I am running Xcode 5.1.1 on a Macbook Pro Retina Display 13" from November 2012

This problem is very frustrating b/c I can't even progress through the basic programming stuff...

Thanks so much for any help!

-Dan

Answer (score 0):

You have omitted class Two default constructor. You can add it to class definition

```
class Two{
public:
    Two() {}
    One one;
    int doSomething(One* oneArgument);
    int somethingThatCallsDoSomething();
};
```

or somewhere else (like your other methods)

```
Two::Two(){
   //Some constructor code here
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  My main problem in my larger code ended up being that I was neglecting to put the 'Classname::' before the definition for one function...
Your advice helped me figure that out because then I had a working simpler code to compare it to!